# Como eu coloco um texto na mesma linha que um botão do tipo collapse em bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div>
    <p>TROCO</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        ...
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
            texto que aparece quando pressiono o botão
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O código é esse aí, queria que o texto "TROCO" aparecesse na mesma linha que o botão, quando eu abro a página eles ficam em linhas diferentes, e se eu coloco o texto dentro do < button> o texto vai pra dentro do botão... Alguém manja o que que ta acontecendo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `<p>` é um elemento `block`, ou  seja ele ocupa a linha inteira (100%) da largura da tela, por isso o botão não fica au lado. Uma forma de corrigir isso é por exemplo trocar o `<p>` por um `<span>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como fica no código:

```html
 <div>
    <span>TROCO</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        ...
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
            texto que aparece quando pressiono o botão
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Ei, eu to usando o span né, aí tipo, quando eu tento editar o texto dentro do span, eu não consigo mudar o estilo dele, mudar a fonte e o posicionamento, você sabe me dizer como que faz??

Comment: @Jingas cara isso eh o básico do CSS, o melhor que vc tem a fazer eh entrar no YouTube e procurar um curso de CSS, la tem vários e eh de graça